# Really slow external drives benchmark

Tags: kde, backup, usb-drive, drive, benchmarks

Hello I have a Linux computer (Ubuntu 18.04 for the core) and I have 3 desktop environments (KDE Plasma, XFCE and Budgie)

I was testing the KDE Plasma DE and I was really happy with it so I decided to make a backup to install Kubuntu on a fresh installation.

But the backup was very slow and I descovered something not cool with KDE, I cannot see the progress bar. So I switched on budgie and had the same issue. I done some benchmark tests and I got the following results:

First: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2Bzn.jpg

Second: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vkhfe.jpg

More I make tests, worst are the results. I thought it was KDE specific but I tried on my two others and the results are sometimes better than KDE but really still very weird.

Something even more weird with this flash drive:

Flash drive: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWS0O.jpg

It's the same weird curve all the time.

Do you have clues to solve this issue?

Comment: In my experience, adding multiple desktops complicates things and creates issues that any desktop/system on it's own doesn't have. I'm unsure of what system you started with, order added, but mentioning Ubuntu 18.04 makes me think of GNOME meaning 4 desktops; *Ubuntu for the core* also could mean Ubuntu Core/IoT release?? When you added your desktops, did you get any file clashes, did you note them & what systems were involved? (those easily dismissed messages are clues as to future problems you may now be experiencing).  Note: I'm writing this as a user who bloats my systems with many DEs

Comment: Sorry for the very late answer but this is how I started:
1. Ubuntu Budgie (based on GNOME)
2. KDE Plasma
3. XFCE

I am currently on XFCE. I never had conflicts of files with the different systems as far as I remember.